# EF Core differences for getting IDs causes issues with Instead Of Trigger and Scope_Identity

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

#### Backstory

I have an application I am trying to move to .NET Core.  This application has undergone a lot of maintenance.  To try to upgrade the application while the original was in use, it got Database Views placed over most of the tables.

These database views use *Instead Of* triggers.  So when an insert is performed on the view, the trigger adds the records to the correct tables.

However, when Entity Framework does an insert, it adds a select statement right after to get out any IDs (and any generated dates).  For lack of a better term, I am calling this the "Turnaround Query".  This select uses Scope_Identity to find the correct row.  But the actual insert took place inside the *Instead Of* trigger.  So `Scope_Identity()` returns null.

To work around that in normal (full) .Net, the select statements were added to the *Instead Of* triggers.  Entity Framework 6 would still add its call, but it would take the first result and be happy.  (The second call would have empty results, but was ignored.)

#### Question

Now I am migrating to .NET Core 3 (and EF Core).  When I run an insert statement, it has two result sets (just like it did in normal (full) .NET Framework).

However, it seems that this workaround no longer functions.  I get the following error after the insert:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I can only assume that it is looking at the second set now (I can't see any other reason for the error).

**Is there a way to tell .NET Core (EF Core) how to look for the result of its "Turnaround Query"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this one out.  Entity Framework Core still takes the first result.  But Entity Framework 6 was willing to ignore a missing column, where Entity Framework Core gave the "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error.

So, if you get this error, look at what columns Entity Framework Core is expecting (via a profiler (like MiniProfiler)) and make sure it matches what is in your *Instead of* trigger.